# displaying results from sqlite database query

Tags: python, html, sql, sqlite, cgi

I have created a CGI webpage with a search box. My script queries an sqlite database with the input from the search box.

Now, I want to display (on my webpage) all columns of the rows that matched the search, but when I do the following:

```
query = raw_input(desc)
query = '%' + query + '%'
cursor.execute("SELECT * from Table WHERE Column LIKE ?", (query,))
print cursor.fetchall
```

the webpage only displays the query itself - no results from the database.

Any ideas how I can get the results to display?

Comment: You should actually call `fetchall` and not only reference it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to **call** `cursor.fetchall()`; you are merely displaying the *representation of the method* otherwise:

```
print cursor.fetchall()
```

The reason you are not seeing anything is because the representation of a method object in Python uses angle brackets, like a HTML tag:

```
>>> print c.fetchall
<built-in method fetchall of sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x11059d9d0>
```

Your browser doesn't know anything about a `<built-in>` HTML tag and just doesn't display it.

You may want to create an actual table with the results:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from Table WHERE Column LIKE ?", (query,))
print '<table>'

for row in cursor:
    print '<tr>{}</tr>'.format(''.join(['<td>{}</td>'.format(col) for col in row]))

print '</table>'
```

Comment: It would be great if I could create this table! But I tried replacing my fetchall command with the table commands you suggested, and I am still getting the query itself in the display.

Comment: Neither the code in your question nor my answer would ever display the SQL query, unless you mean the whole script source code is being displayed. Do *any* changes in the script show in the browser? Are you certain the right file is being altered here?

Comment: I think I used the wrong term. It's displaying whatever was input into the search box on the site. So if I type "Gene" into the box, the results show "Gene", and nothing else.

Comment: Right, but nowhere in this or your code is `query` printed. If you added `print "Hello!"`, do you see that in your browser? If not, then this script is not what is being run.

Comment: Yes, print "Hello!" prints Hello! to the browser.

Comment: Right, then you can at least build from there. Try a query without a filter; just `SELECT * FROM Table` with no `WHERE` clause. Small steps to narrow down the problem.